# Sending crypted message from python client to nodejs server

Tags: python, node.js, cryptography

Here I have 2 programs.

**client side** is a python program. It needs send encrypted message to server through socket. It's using pycryptodome package to encrypt the message. mode is DES.

```python
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
from Crypto.Util import Padding
import socket

message=b"abc"
key = b"secret_k"

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host ='127.0.0.1'
port =8007
serversocket.connect((host,port))

#need to do the padding manually
des = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)
# ciphered = des.encrypt(message)
ciphered = des.encrypt(Padding.pad(message,8))

plain_msg_withpadding = des.decrypt(ciphered)
# plain_msg = Padding.unpad(plain_withpadding,8)

print ("Deciphered including padding: ", plain_withpadding)
# print ("Decipered without padding: ", plain_msg)


print('msg_to_send', ciphered)
serversocket.send(ciphered)
serversocket.close()
```

**server side** is a nodejs program. It needs interpret the message received. It's using crypto package for nodejs. Mode is also set to DES

```js
var net = require('net');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const decipher = crypto.createDecipher('DES-ECB','secret_k');
const local_decipher = crypto.createDecipher('DES-ECB','secret_k');
const cipher = crypto.createCipher('DES-ECB','secret_k')

function encrypt (buf){
    let crypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(buf),cipher.final()]);
    return crypted
}

local_message = 'abc'
local_cyphered = encrypt(Buffer.from(local_message));
console.log('cyphered in buffer', local_cyphered);

console.log('local_message decyphered: ', 
local_decipher.update(local_cyphered)+local_decipher.final());


net.createServer(function(socket){

socket.on('data', function(data){
    decipher.setAutoPadding(false);// have to disable auto padding, otherwise final() will raise and error.
    var totalBuffer = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(data),decipher.final()]);

    console.log('decrypted remote message: ',totalBuffer);
    console.log('decrypted remote message in utf-8: ',totalBuffer.toString('utf-8'));

})
}).listen(8007);

console.log("server started at 8007 \n");
```

when I run the client program it print the result:

```
Deciphered including padding:  b'abc\x05\x05\x05\x05\x05'
msg_to_send b'\t\xc3JkP\xca\xd0\xf7'
```

but on the server side the result comes out like:

```
cyphered in buffer <Buffer 4f c1 e4 2c fc dd eb 67>
local_message decyphered:  abc
server started at 8007

decrypted remote message:  <Buffer 74 d2 47 08 cd 45 bb 6a>
decrypted remote message in utf-8:  t��E�j
```

**How can I make the server properly decrypt the message send by client?** need your expert guide. Thank you!

Comment: Use AES not DES, it is no more difficult to use and AES is secure while DES is no longer secure. Do not use ECB mode, it is not secure, use CBC with a random IV or GCM mode if available.

Comment: Thank you, Actually it is for a communication to a legacy system using DEC. If it is for a total new system I will use AES.

Comment: So an insecure system will be continued, it that really a defensible choice? I guess the security is not important. Interesting because so many times it is claimed that the security flaws will be resolved in the next revision and here we are at that revision, I guess this is proof that is not be true in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to decompose your problem: the message sending and encryption / decryption should be tested separately.

If you use `createCipher` and `createDecipher` you have to provide a password, not a key. The password gets preprocessed to create a key, but then the keys will obviously differ from the client side keys, giving you garbage when you try to decrypt. You need to use `createCipheriv` or `createDecipheriv` to use a key. However, last time I checked, ECB doesn't work well with those methods. It may be a good idea to use a cipher mode that requires an IV anyway; an authenticated mode such as AES-GCM would be most beneficial.

The `setAutoPadding(false)` call should not be necessary. If you disable it it is probably because the decryption fails, and then the decryption result doesn't make sense.

Note that reusing a cipher within the Node.js package is dangerous. You should recreate the cipher object for each message to encrypt / decrypt.

Comment: thank you for your reply I will try your suggested, and report back

Comment: The IV is usually a fixed: length: the block size for most modes (8 bytes for DES, 16 for AES), and GCM requires 12 bytes. As the size is known in advance you can simply prefix it to the ciphertext; the IV can be send in plain.

Comment: Thank you Maarten, I have rewrite 2 program now they can have the communication I want.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Maarten, I have rewrite 2 program according to your hint.Now they can have the communication I want. I know there may be some security issues, but I will improve this later

```python
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
from Crypto.Util import Padding
import socket

host ='127.0.0.1'
port =8007

greeting=bytes("hello!",encoding="utf-8")
message=bytes("abc这个",encoding="utf-8")
key = b"secret_k"

def ba(byte_data):
  return list(map(hex,bytearray(byte_data))) 

def post_message(msg):
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.connect((host,port))
    serversocket.send(msg)
    serversocket.close()

#1 test normal connection server should print hello!
post_message(greeting)
print ('plain text', ba(greeting))


#2 test encrypt
padded_msg = Padding.pad(message,8) #need to do the padding manually

des = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_CBC) #using CBC instead of ECB
ciphered = des.encrypt(des.iv+padded_msg)

post_message(ciphered)
print("ciphered : ",ba(ciphered))
```

on the server

```js
var net = require('net');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const key = 'secret_k';

//prepare the cipher with shared key 'secret_k'
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('DES-CBC',key,'iv123456');

var notFirstMessage = false;//just a flag

net.createServer(function(socket){

    socket.on('data', function(data){

        if(notFirstMessage){

            console.log("I will do decipher work\n");
            console.log("encrypted data is: ", data);

            //do the decipher here
            var remote_message = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(data),decipher.final()]);
            console.log("After decipher: ",remote_message.slice(8).toString());//remove the iv
        }else {
            //
            console.log('connection is ok, I got data: ',data.toString());
            notFirstMessage = true;
            console.log("============[Plain Text Connection OK]==============\n")
        }
    });
}).listen(8007);

console.log("server started at 8007 \n");
```

Hope above sample can help other guys facing same issue.

Comment: The IV should be random, different for each encryption, just prefix the encrypted data with it, it does not need to be secret.

Comment: @zaph That's nothing compared to the CBC padding oracle attacks that are likely to be possible :)

Comment: Doesn't matter, the decryption always fails, the failure is not noticed and not returned to the client.